# Apache Camel Dynamic Http call

Tags: rest, apache-camel

I have a need to be able to poll a Rest WebService and as part of that call pass in the id of the last response from the WebService. I am aware that to use dynamic endpoints in Camel you need to use an Enrich processor, but I cant get the update to be made.

Please consider the following simple case:

```
public class MyRoute extends RouteBuilder {

long id;

@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {

    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=3000")
            .enrich().simple("http://localhost:8080/TestRestSource/test/result/" + id)
            .process(new Processor() {
                @Override
                public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception {
                    id++;
                    System.out.println("--- " + id);
                }
            })
            .end();
    }

}
```

I am using Camel 2.16.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Chris

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Answer (score 1):

The configure method is only invoked once during creating the Camel routes, so you cannot use `+ id` to build the uri for each call. Instead use a java method call to build the uri dynamic.

And dont use `enrich` by just a plain `recipientList` which is dynamic, where you can do a method call that calculates the uri to use:

```
from("timer:...").
  recipientList(method(MyRoute.class, "calculateUri"))
```

And then add a method calculateUri in the route builder class where you return the uri to use

```
public String calculateUri() {
  return "http:...." + i;
}
```

Comment: How could one pass the response and get input `i` as an axample from the response? Thanks